# How can I decide using Java which parameter to send when touching the screen once or twice?

Tags: java, android

I have a get method where I send to a server two parameters:

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr="http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=start&cmd=stop";
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);

            byte[] bufOut;



            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. We don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

And inside a touchEvent I did:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    circlePath.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            byte[] response = Get(null);
                            if (response!=null)
                            {
                                String a = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    a = new String(response,"UTF-8");
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // nothing to do
                    circlePath.reset();

                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

This is working fine sending two parameters but now I want to change it and make that when I touch once the Android screen it will send the first parameter: start.

And if I touch after it twice the screen (double touch) it will send the second parameter: stop.

1. How do I know if I touched the screen once or twice?
2. How do I make that when I touch once it will send the start parameter and when touching twice it will send the second parameter stop?
3. How do I make so it will know if I touch each time once or double? Like a double click if I clicked once or if I clicked twice and then to send the right parameter?

Comment: Please, method names allways in lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed(android.view.MotionEvent))

*See at the bottom for setup*

1. The method `onSingleTapConfirmed(..)` will trigger when the app is sure it's not a double tap (or triple or more). The method `onDoubleTap(..)` will trigger at double tap.

2.
For single tap:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    // DO STUFF FOR SINGLE TOUCH

    /*
    This return statement says that this method was handled (true)
        or
    This return statement says that this method was not handled (false)
     */
    return true;
}
```

For double tap:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    // DO STUFF FOR DOUBLE TAP 

    //see above for notes on return statement 
    return true;
}
```

3. See number (1)

**Setup:**

- Add `implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
  GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` to your class header.
- Add field variable :   `private GestureDetector gestureDetector;`
- Add the following to your onCreate(..) method:

  `gestureDetector= new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
  gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);`
- Because you're using interface, you'll need to override more methods which you may or may not use. Just go with it. For example:

  `@Override
      public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
          // not gonna use it, but ok :/ 
          return false;  // so it doesn't consume the event 
      }`

More on this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Answer (score 1):

1) you can either use a GestureRecognizer or have a member variable called timeOfLastTouch. Then on touch you check to see how long it was since the last click. Hence a double click.

```
private long timeOfLastTouch ;


public void OnTouch()
{  
// i have used 300ms as a time frame in which you have to complete your clicks

     if ( timeOfLastTouch + 300 >System.CurrentTimeMiliSeconds())
     {
     // Double touch
     }else { 
     // Single touch
     }
 // reset the variable 
timeOfLastTouch  = System.CurrentTimeMiliSeconds();
}
```